# CSS table and list-style-position bug? Workaround?

Tags: html, css, list, google-chrome, css-tables

I have an unordered list with `display: table;` and `list-style-position: inside;`. The problem is on Google Chrome, the list items don't take up full width, but instead wrap to the next line.

http://jsfiddle.net/ntbq5/

Funny enough this doesn't always happen, so if you don't see what I'm talking about try clicking the "Run" button - here's what I'm seeing:

[image]

If I refresh the fiddle, somehow it appears normal again...http://i40.tinypic.com/30hr4gl.gif. Firefox and IE it appears normal as well. But on a real website, refreshing doesn't change anything for me. What's the solution?

**EDIT:** My bad, I forgot to say I need to center my table as well so I can't use 100% width http://jsfiddle.net/ntbq5/10/ What else can be done?

Comment: On your fiddle if you resize the left panel the problem disappear

Comment: Indeed, but on a live website this isn't the case for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use `White-space:nowrap;` to overcome this issue.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ntbq5/3/)**

**The Code Change:**

```
ul {
    display: table;
    list-style-position: inside;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do need the text to wrap in case the text length exceeds the container width.

Comment: I agree and was just debugging the issue. The issue is in chrome when you press run. After you press run, when you just move your left pane to any pixel (whether left or right), it will regain the position and shall make your thing work fine. But, nevertheless, if you are using media queries, you can control `whitespacing`. Anyways, What chrome version are you using?? - @Sunny

Comment: I'm on Chrome 30. It works well on the fiddle, but on some other site it doesn't always work.

Comment: I made an edit to the original post, I forgot to mention that I need to center my table, so I can't use 100% width.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just define a width for the li elements:

```
li {
    width: 150px;
}
```

Here a screen of the fiddle where i added this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ntbq5/embedded/result/

Comment: But what if the `<li>` element has text with a width larger than 150px?

Comment: `li{
    width: auto;
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can add width 100% to your `<ul>` elements.

CSS:

```
ul {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
   list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Comment: You're right but I forgot to mention my table is centered with margin: 0 auto; http://jsfiddle.net/ntbq5/4/

Comment: Ok, adding `white-space: nowrap;` to the `<li>` element will fix this.

Comment: [Agreed ;) - @JamieRead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631954/css-table-and-list-style-position-bug-workaround/19631976#19631976)

Answer (score 1):

You are displaying the `ul` as table and table's width should be defined for fine looking. So you need to set width for that ul. So use this:

```
ul {
    display: table;
    list-style-position: inside;
    width: 100%;
}
```

As you mentioned your ul tag is having margin auto in the comment, you could assign text-align to center

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ntbq5/7/)

Comment: The problem with text-align: center is the bullets are no longer aligned together.